# Google maps javascript eventproblem

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to do some event-listeners for my homepage. But I can only register one event. The event that works for me is adding Marker's and a circle to it. But when im trying to do something else like rigthclicking on the marker to delete it or get the radius off the circle when the radius is changed.
Anyone know what im doing wrong? I also have problems with the showning the map. The map gets loaded and i can see everything except the map.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_areas"), {
    zoom:8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: { style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE},
    overviewMapControl: true,
    panControl: true
});

var marker;
var circle;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
    addMarkerAndCircle(evt);
});

function addMarkerAndCircle(evt) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:  evt.latLng,
        animations: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map:map,
        draggable: true,
        clickable:true
    });
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map:map,
        radius:16093, // 10 miles in metres
        fillColor:'#AA0000',
        clickable: true,
        editable: true
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    markersArray.push(marker);
    circleArray.push(circle);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function() {
    var radius = circle.getRadius();
});
```

http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/6739/googlemapsv.jpg

Comment: I've seen that map-partially-loaded issue when I've initiated a map inside a hidden div, to be shown at a later point. Is that what you're doing? In that case, would it be possible to initiate the map at the point of displaying the div instead?

Comment: So does this line work or not?  Presumably you then want to do something with the radius... var radius = circle.getRadius();

Comment: I think the line works :). But the event.addlistener dosent. I want to get the radius from the circle and save it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your need to attach the circle event listener to the circle when it is created. In your code you are adding a listener to a circle that is not defined yet. Try this:

```
function addMarkerAndCircle(evt) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position:  evt.latLng,
       animations: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
       map:map,
       draggable: true,
       clickable:true
    });
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
       map:map,
       radius:16093, // 10 miles in metres
       fillColor:'#AA0000',
       clickable: true,
       editable: true
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    addRadiusChanged(circle);
    markersArray.push(marker);
    circleArray.push(circle);
}

function addRadiusChanged(c) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(c, 'radius_changed', function() {
        var radius = c.getRadius();
        // do something with radius
    });
```

You can get the map to resize itself to fill the div with this:

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
```